# Macbook Air - same in Australia as UK?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am looking at buying a Macbook Air in Australia whilst I am here on holiday. When I get back to the UK will it work?

Comment: The keyboard layouts can differ in countries, check the Australian layout and see if you are happy working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason it should not work. Bear in mind though that you may have to pay customs fees when returning (I do not know what the laws for the commonwealth are).

Answer (score 2):

You will need an adapter for your charger as Australia uses type I plug/socket but UK uses type G